# Find missing values in a range across a partition, then forward fill values?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking to find missing entries in a field, grouped by two columns as a partition, then forward fill the missing entries.

Table I have:

```
England    Q1        1     Dogs
England    Q1        2     Dogs
England    Q1        3     Dogs
Germany    Q1        1     Dogs
Germany    Q2        1     Cats
Germany    Q2        2     Cats
France     Q1        1     Cats
France     Q2        1     Cats
```

So let's say my range is 1 - 3, for every unique [Country][Quarter] combo, I want a full 1,2,3 in the [Number] column, with the [Animal] column forward filling the previous entry.

Table I want:

```
England    Q1        1     Dogs
England    Q1        2     Dogs
England    Q1        3     Dogs
Germany    Q1        1     Dogs
Germany    Q1        2     Dogs
Germany    Q1        3     Dogs
Germany    Q2        1     Cats
Germany    Q2        2     Cats
Germany    Q2        3     Cats
France     Q1        1     Cats
France     Q1        2     Cats
France     Q1        3     Cats
France     Q2        1     Cats
France     Q2        2     Cats
France     Q2        3     Cats
```

Let me know if this doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1):

Use `cross join` to generate the rows.  Then use `left join` to bring in a value and a window function to fill in the missing values:

```
select cq.country, cq.quarter, n.number,
       max(t.animal) over (partition by cq.country, cq.quarter) as animal
from (select distinct country, quarter from t) cq cross join
     (select distinct number from t) n left join
     t
     on t.country = cq.country and t.quarter = cq.quarter and t.number = q.number;
```

Note:  This does rely on all example of the numbers being in the table.  It is easy enough to use:

```
from (select distinct country, quarter from t) cq cross join
     (select 1 as number union all
      select 2 as number union all
      select 3 as number
     ) n left join
     . . .
```

Comment: This does rely on the values needed being in the data already. For example, in the "number" column only had the values 1 & 2 in it and you needed a 3, to satisfy your answer you'd need to pull that criteria from another table

Comment: @Bobbylank . . . The sample data has examples of all the numbers.  But I did modify the answer.

Comment: I know, I wasn't criticising the answer which was spot on for the example given, just pointing it out for Marc in case he didn't realise

Comment: So when I run this: country, quarter and number are as desired, but instead of animal forward filling, it just returns the max() across the quarter/year period. 

In my actual dataset, I have multiple 'animal' columns that are ints and floats, how do I fix this?